# Nested dictionary from multiple lists

Tags: python

I have an API that takes in two sets of lists and returns a singular list of elements for corresponding values.

```
Symbol = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
Field = ['J','K','L','M']
```

Would return a list like:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

This needs to be constructed into a nested dictionary such as below:

```
{'A': {'J': 0, 'K': 1, 'L': 2, 'M': 3},
 'B': {'J': 4, 'K': 5, 'L': 6, 'M': 7},
 'C': {'J': 8, 'K': 9, 'L': 10, 'M': 11},
 'D': {'J': 12, 'K': 13, 'L': 14, 'M': 15},
 'E': {'J': 16, 'K': 17, 'L': 18, 'M': 19},
 'F': {'J': 20, 'K': 21, 'L': 22, 'M': 23},
 'G': {'J': 24, 'K': 25, 'L': 26, 'M': 27},
 'H': {'J': 28, 'K': 29, 'L': 30, 'M': 31},
 'I': {'J': 32, 'K': 33, 'L': 34, 'M': 35}}
```

Currently my code is functional and is as below, however is there a cleaner / faster method for when the size of the Symbol or Field list grows to 100s of elements - as this needs to be fed into another function and then refreshed as quickly as possible.

```
Nested = {}
i=0
for symbol in Symbol:
    coll = {}
    for field in Field:
        coll[field] = Values[i]
        i += 1
    Nested[symbol] = coll
```

Comment: Python convention is for all variables to be lowercase (possibly with underscores), hence `Symbol`,`Field`,`Nested`.

Comment: and those aren't "two sets of lists", they're two lists.

Comment: There might be a way to do it with nested dictionary comprehensions, but it won't be as readable. And the code is the same no matter how many elements there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's built-in data structures and methods as much as possible, so that the code becomes more readable and performance is guaranteed.

In this situation, you can use `product` function to generate all the data pairs, and use `defaultdict` to save the data.

You can use `defaultdict` in the same way as `dict`.

```py
Symbol = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
Field = ['J','K','L','M']

from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

Nested = defaultdict(dict)

for count,(symbol, field) in enumerate(product(Symbol, Field)):
  Nested[symbol][field] = count

Nested = dict(Nested)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use an iterator over the list of numbers, and use the `next(...)` function to get the elements from it in sequence.

```py
symbols = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
fields = ['J','K','L','M']
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

data_iter = iter(data)
nested = {
    symbol: {field: next(data_iter) for field in fields}
    for symbol in symbols
}
```

Comment: -16 bytes ;) `symbol: dict(zip(fields, data_iter))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for both lists in a nested dict comprehension to calculate and output the mapped values:

```
{s: {f: i * len(Field) + j for j, f in enumerate(Field)} for i, s in enumerate(Symbol)}
```